# Fill area in between lines

Tags: plotting

I want to obtain a shape formed by the area enclosed by or in between `Line[]` objects. The lines have been extracted from various types of plots. There can be a `GeometricTransformation` acting on the `Line` that need to be maintained.

A simplified example would be to go from

```
{Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}}], 
 Graphics[GeometricTransformation[
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], {{{1, -1}, {0, -1}}, {0, 0}}]]}
```

to a shape like

```
Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 0}}]
```

but of course in an automatic way dealing with lines consisting of many points.

It seems to me that the `Filling` functions unfortunately are expecting functions or data directly instead of the Line objects produced by plots.

P.S.:
It might be easier to work within a plot directly so that I can use the standard `Filling` techniques but in that case I need at the very least a clever way to deal with rotating interpolated functions. If I want `f[x]` but rotated by an angle theta that is easy to do by acting with the rotation on points or on a `Line` but not easy to work on the interpolation function directly. I guess I can convert the lines to points and create `ListLinePlot`'s from that but is there a better way to work directly with the Line objects? (P.P.S.: The enclosed region is not necessarily convex.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, generating nonconvex polygons is nontrivial unless you have an algorithm for determining which point to go to next. There's a pretty nice [NonConvexHullMesh](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonConvexHullMesh) function in the repository that we can make use of.

```
linepts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}};
transformpts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
geotrans = {{1, -1}, {0, -1}}.# + {0, 0} & /@ transformpts;
polypts = Union[linepts, geotrans];
mesh = ResourceFunction["NonConvexHullMesh"][polypts, 10]
```

[image: Final calculated region.]

I'm using the raw points here, but if your points are already in the form of lines, you can always extract the points using something like `Cases[myline, {_,_}]` to get the points back. `GeometricTransformation` states that `GeometricTransformation[object, {m, v}]` yields `m.r + v` for each point `r` in `object`, so I'm using that definition since the transformation doesn't seem to actually apply until you put it into a `Graphics` form.

In the `ResourceFunction`, the second argument (I have 10) is the sensitivity. Depending on the number of points and how closely spaced they are, you may have to adjust this sensitivity. As I mentioned before, non-convex hulls are difficult. If you know enough about the points beforehand, you may be able to come up with an efficient method of selecting the points directly.